# Run Vagrant machine on remote server but use as local

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, vagrant, ssh-tunnel

I'm not quite sure if I can really do it in that way:

Scenario at the moment:
My laptop is running a vagrant machine "[laravel/homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead)" to serve as a webserver. To run it and connect to it - I type `vagrant up && vagrant ssh`.
So while developing, all the processing, compilation, writing, copying, moving etc. is on the laptop's responsibilites. And it exceeds it's hardware resources, laptop is start working slow.

Scenario I would like to establish:
I want to run a vagrant machine on my personal pc (Remote PC) from my laptop via the same vagrant command `vagrant up`.
So, basically all the processing and heavy load will be on Remote PC, and laptop will be used for manipulating the remote pc.

I tried to setup on remote PC a vagrant file with this configuration:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.18"
```

`192.168.1.18` is set to accept incoming traffic on port `2222` by port forwarding configured in router settings.

But I can't run it  via `vagrant connect 192.168.1.18:2222`

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Hey did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: yeah, I did, but forgot to give an answer here. I will check out and post an answer

Comment: @aspirinemaga If you could add the answer that would be really helpful

Comment: @CamiloCasadiego I hardly recall how I have done it. Try edit your Vagrant file with following line: ‘config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 2222, host_ip: "localhost", id: "ssh", auto_correct: true‘ and connect to your remote machine with it's actual IP address: ssh vagrant@192.168.11.15 -p 2222

Comment: @CamiloCasadiego - try this one, this worked for me `ssh vagrant@192.168.11.15 -p 2222`